# Toolbar buttons are disabled by default for Lion Cocoa app

Tags: cocoa, xcode4, nstoolbar, nstoolbaritem

I've created an interface nib/xib file. The app is basically working, which is cool. The standard toolbar buttons look bad, they're glossy and raised, while most apps in Lion have the flat, inner bevel look. So I created some image toolbar buttons and put them in the toolbar and they look great, but they're all disabled by default.

Is there a way to give these the correct state in InterfaceBuilder or do I have to use code to give them the proper state.

Cocoa and Objective C are very unfamiliar so it would be helpful to me if I just knew what to search for. Most of my searching brings me results for creating custom buttons for iOS.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out, here's what you do:

In the nib/xib file, double click your menu bar to show the "allowed toolbar items" sheet. From here, choose your button that you've created. In my case I'll select a back button that I want to connect to a webview control. Ctrl click + drag from the button to what you want to connect it to and then make the appropriate connection. In my case I choose goBack from the WebView.

Once it has a connection it now becomes active.